# problem blending properly in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, blending

I'm trying to draw a 2d character sprite on top of a 2d tilemap, but when I draw the character he's got odd stuff behind him. This isn't in the sprite, so I think its the blending.

This is how my openGL is set up:

```
void InitGL(int Width, int Height)          // We call this right after our OpenGL window is created.
{

    glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);       // This Will Clear The Background Color To Black
    glClearDepth(1.0);              // Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);               // The Type Of Depth Test To Do
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);           // Enables Depth Testing
    //glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);          // Enables Smooth Color Shading
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                        // Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE , GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.5f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);//configuring projection matrix now
    glLoadIdentity();//reset matrix
    glOrtho(0, Width, 0, Height, 0.0f, 100.0f);//set a 2d projection matrix

}
```

How should I set this up to work properly (i.e. drawing the sprite without odd stuff behind him.

This is what I am talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmotJ.png

PS: I need to be able to put transparent/semi-transparent images on top of each other and have whats behind them visible too

Comment: You normally should not "set up" OpenGL. All of the state you set in InitGL should be set on a as-needed base in the display function. There's only very little that initialized one time in OpenGL, namely textures and buffer objects. Once you wrapped your mind around the fact, that you can enable/disable blending at any time and should do so based on the needs of the current stage in rendering a scene, thins get a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your sprite have premultiplied alpha?  Your `glBlendFunc` setup is a little unusual, if you don't have premultiplied alpha it could definitely be causing the issue.